# Android BLE write data on multiple BLE h/w simultaneously

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an android app where I am using android BLE api for connecting to sensor devices.Things are going good but I am connecting 4 BLE h/w devices with my android app but when I try to write some data on all 4 BLe devices at same time it only writes data on a single device and I can't write data on all devices simultaneously.

Here is my code to write data on single BLE device:

```
if(btWriteGattChar == null)
            return;
        btWriteGattChar.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        btWriteGattChar.setValue(dat);
        mBluetoothGatt[tabIndex].writeCharacteristic(btWriteGattChar);
```

The above code works find for single BLE device but it won't allow me to write the same data on all rest of devices.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong step to write same data on multiple BLE devices.

Comment: You might have written to the same bluetoothDevice. Check once again whether you're writing to the same device using the bluetoothdevice.getAddress() method which returns the hardware address of every remote device.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just can't do that. It is not stated in the document, but all the BLE operation is actually synchronous.

The api itself is asynchronous, but the BLE stack can only do it one by one. 
For example, after calling writeCharacteristic, you have to wait for onCharacteristicWrite before you write it to another device/characteristic, or else you will get undefined behaviour. You may, or may not write the subsequent characteristic if you do not wait for the callback.

This is true at least up to 4.4.4. I didn't check if this is fixed on 5.0 onwards, though. Anyway if your app supports os version before 5.0 you have to take this into consideration.